# Is it ok to prove that $\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_a(n)}{n}=0\,$ if a > 1 this way?

Tags: limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

Is it ok to prove that $\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log_a(n)}{n}=0\,$ this way ?

I tried to prove it using the definition of the limit:
$$\frac{\log_a(n)}{n}<\epsilon.$$
This means that
$$\frac{1}{n}\log_a(n)<\epsilon \iff n^\frac{1}{n}<a^\epsilon.$$
Because $n^\frac{1}{n}\leq n$ if $n$ is a natural number, we can replace $n^\frac{1}{n}$ with $n$ (if we replace $<$ with $\leq$):
$n\leq a^\epsilon$.
Consequently, $N = [a^\epsilon]+1$.

Any mistakes there?

In my textbook it was proved using the squeeze theorem

Comment: This seems correct. In your actual solution, you should be more formal ("let $\epsilon>0$. We are looking for a natural $N$ such that for all $n>N$....").

Comment: For a fixed $a$, will $a^{\epsilon}$ be very large or very close to one?

Comment: This doesn't work. You would need $n\leq a^\epsilon$ for every $n\geq N$, which won't hold.

Comment: @ИринаМухомор, pay attention: $$\frac{1}{n}\log_a(n)<\epsilon \iff n^\frac{1}{n}<a^\epsilon$$ is false if $\,0<a<1$.

Comment: @ИринаМухомор, moreover $\;\dfrac{\log_a(n)}n<0\;$ if $\;0<a<1\;$ and $\;n\geqslant2\;,\;$ consequently you should write $\;\left\vert\dfrac{\log_a(n)}{n}\right\vert<\epsilon\;$ instead of $\;\dfrac{\log_a(n)}{n}<\epsilon\;.$

Comment: @Angelo , would it work if a was greater  than 1?

Comment: @Angelo if $a>1$, you would still have the problem of the claim
$$\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}^*\ \forall n\geq n_0: n\leq a^\epsilon$$
which isn't true since that would imply that the natural numbers ar bounded.

Comment: Sorry, I meant @ИринаМухомор

Comment: @DankaMakabre, I completely agree with you. Also for $a>1$, what OP wrote is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is not quite right because, formalizing it, it would be correct if
$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}^*\ \forall n\geq n_0:n\leq a^\epsilon$$
but this is impossible since it would also imply that the natural numbers are bounded by $a^\epsilon$. It is true that $\exists n_0:n_0\leq a^\epsilon$ as you pointed out. But that isn't enough to prove the desired limit since you need that $\forall n\geq n_0:n\leq a^\epsilon$ which is impossible.

The right way of proving it is to notice that your limit is $$\lim_n\log_a(n)/n=\lim_n\log_a(\sqrt[n]{n})=\log_a(\lim_n\sqrt[n]{n})=\log_a(1)=0$$
which makes use of the well-known fact $\lim_n\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ and that $\log_a(x)$ is continuous. However, if you can't use these results, I will show an alternative proof of the said limit.

First, we will prove that $\log(n)/n\to0$ by [the squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem). If $n\geq2$, then
$$n=\left[1+(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)\right]^n=1+\binom{n}{1}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)+\binom{n}{2}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2+\dots+(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$$
$$n\geq\binom{n}{2}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2\geq0\Rightarrow \frac{2}{n-1}=\frac{n}{\binom{n}{2}}\geq(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2\geq0\Rightarrow 1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\geq \sqrt[n]{n}\geq1$$
$$\log\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\right)\geq\frac{\log n}{n}\geq\log(1)=0$$
$$\text{Finally, since }\lim_n\log\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\right)=\log(1)=0, \text{ we have that} \lim_n\frac{\log n}{n}=0$$
Now, noticing that $\log_a(n)=\frac{\log n}{\log a}$, we finally get
$$\boxed{\therefore\lim_n\frac{\log_a n}{n}=\frac{1}{\log a}\lim_n\frac{\log n}{n}=0}$$